# Is there a way I can use a function to return the memory location of an array element?

Tags: c++

I just started learning about pointers so I'd thought I'd share what I'm trying to do. Of a character array (let's call it c and it's equal to "Hello"), I'm trying to return the memory location of a certain element. Say the memory of location of 'l'. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* str_char(char* c_ptr, char c);

int main()
{
    char *c = "Hello";


    cout << str_char(c, 'l') << endl;

    return 0;
}


char* str_char(char* c_ptr, char c)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(c_ptr); i++)
    {
        if (*(c_ptr + i) == c)
        {
            return (c_ptr + i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

After I use the function, it outputs "llo".

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `str_char()`  exposes undefined behavior in case nothing is returned!

Comment: What did you expect it to output?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you. I'll look into that before I ask a future question

Comment: @molbdnilo I was hoping the function would return the memory location of an array element

Comment: note that there is a standard function `std::strchr` that does just what your function is trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earlier answer has covered the bugs, so I'll just answer the actual question...

The function *does* return the location of an array element.

The `<<` operator treats every `char*` as a pointer to a zero-terminated string, and outputting the result of `str_char` works exactly like outputting `c`; it prints every character after that location until it encounters a zero.

If you want to output the value of the location itself, you need to cast it to a different type:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(str_char(c, 'l')) << endl;
```

as `<<` has an overload for `void*` that outputs the address itself.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much! Can you explain why you casted it to a void? Just want to understand it clearly

Comment: Sure does. Thanks again

Comment: oh, Op never said it should output address.. mainly a useless info, unless one does debugging..

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. However, there are a few things that are not right.

1. Use of `sizeof(c_ptr)` is not right. It works for your case due to happy coincidence.

   `sizeof(c_ptr)` is equal to `sizeof(char*)`. It is not equal to the size of the array from the calling function.
2. There is a missing `return` statement at end of the function -- the case where `c` is not found in `c_ptr`.
3. There is no need of the `break;` after the `return;`.

Also, you can simplify the function a little bit.

Here's an updated version:

```
char* str_char(char* c_ptr, char c)
{
   for (char* cp = c_ptr; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )
   {
      if (*cp == c)
      {
         return cp;
      }
   }
   return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I really do appreciate the simplification and you making things a lot clearer.

Comment: I might just make it a void function and cout the memory location. I can't seem to return it

Comment: it is often agreed pattern to leave iterator (pointer) pointing at end of line (at the terminating zero) to avoid crash you may cause by returning nullptr

Comment: @Swift, most containers do that but `std::string` does not. It returns `std::string::npos` if the input is not found.

Comment: it returns end() which is  same as npos for string, if I recall right, maybe I'm wrong in that case, but npos is not really a null pointer, it won't cause UB with stream output. I though of more C-style  functions,   the code you made  _almost_ repeats source code of function from C standard library

Answer (score 0):

R Sahu gave you  answer that is slightly modified version of your function . That is legal code, but that is basicly a C code, except use of nullptr. Returning nullptr is non-canon and if nupllptr will be returned, what << operator would do? That's undefined behavior.
it is often agreed pattern to leave iterator (pointer) pointing at end of line (at the terminating zero) to avoid crash you may cause by returning nullptr.

```
char* str_char(char* c_ptr, char c)
{
   char* cp = c_ptr; 

   for (; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )
   {
      if (*cp == c)
      {
         return cp;
      }
   }
   return cp; 
   // if cp was declared inside scope , we can't retirn it's value
}
```

Normally you do not need to write own string functions.. bth C library and C++ got  them already covered. C++ got set of abstract algorithmic functions, in your case a strchr, find  or find_if is prudent:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    char *c = "Hello";


    cout << std::strchr(c, 'l') << '\n';

    // with pointer to null-terminated string, strlen searches 
    // for zero char and returns the count of characters before it
    cout << std::find(c, c + strlen(c), 'l') << '\n';


    // with  declared array we can use std:begin and std::end
    char carr[] = "Hello"; 

    cout << std::find(std::begin(carr),std::end(carr) , 'l') << '\n';


    // with pointer to null-terminated string a lambda expression 
    // can be used to stop at 0 as well as at first key
    const char key = 'l';
    cout << std::find_if(c, c + strlen(c),[=](const char& item)
    {
        return (item ==  key) || (item ==  '\0');
    }) << '\n';


    return 0;

}
```

An std::vector or ::array or other containers can be used with those templates as well.
The `<algorithms>` header would save tons of time you need to debug your custom-tailored functions for search, iteration, etc.

P.S. cout and cin deal with char and char* in special way.. char* is always pointer at string, char is always a character, not a number, so casts are required if you mean otherwise.